# removing multiple characters in multiple lines in text file between '-1' and ',' using python and how to open the file?

Tags: python

my text file contain hundreds of lines like this:

```
#EXTINF:-1 tvg-id="" tvg-name="" tvg-language="Arabic" tvg-logo="http://jascotvs.com/u,Al Alamiya
http://82.212.74.98:8000/live/7815.
#EXTINF:-1 tvg-id="" tvg-name="" tvg-language="Arabic" tvg-logo="" tvg-country="MA" tvg-u,Aoula
https://cdnamd-hls-globecast.akamaized.net/live/ramdisk/al_aoula_inter/hls_snrt/al_aoula_inter.
#EXTINF:-1 tvg-id="" tvg-name="" tvg-language="Arabic",Laayou
http://cdn-hls.globecast.sy/live/ramdisk/al_aoula_laayoune/hls_snrt/index.
```

I need to open the text file in python and just delete the characters that are between '-1' and ',',so the first line I want to delete the characters between '-1' and ',' , then come the second line with the url that I don't want to edit it and doesn't contain '-1' or ',' 
and after that come the third line and this contain the characters between '-1' and ',' that I want to delete and after that come the fourth line that I don't want to edit it and doesn't contain '-1' or ','
and so on .......
so please can anyone help me,I'll be very appreciate and thankful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `re` module for the task ([regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/PtEaS2/1)).

For example:

when `data.txt` contains:

```
#EXTINF:-1 tvg-id="" tvg-name="" tvg-language="Arabic" tvg-logo="http://jascotvs.com/u,Al Alamiya
http://82.212.74.98:8000/live/7815.
#EXTINF:-1 tvg-id="" tvg-name="" tvg-language="Arabic" tvg-logo="" tvg-country="MA" tvg-u,Aoula
https://cdnamd-hls-globecast.akamaized.net/live/ramdisk/al_aoula_inter/hls_snrt/al_aoula_inter.
#EXTINF:-1 tvg-id="" tvg-name="" tvg-language="Arabic",Laayou
http://cdn-hls.globecast.sy/live/ramdisk/al_aoula_laayoune/hls_snrt/index
```

Then:

```
import re

with open('data.txt', 'r') as f_in, open('data_out.txt', 'w') as f_out:
    txt = re.sub(r'(?<=^#EXTINF:)(-1.*,)', '', f_in.read(), flags=re.M)
    print(txt, file=f_out, end='')
```

Produces `data_out.txt`:

```
#EXTINF:Al Alamiya
http://82.212.74.98:8000/live/7815.
#EXTINF:Aoula
https://cdnamd-hls-globecast.akamaized.net/live/ramdisk/al_aoula_inter/hls_snrt/al_aoula_inter.
#EXTINF:Laayou
http://cdn-hls.globecast.sy/live/ramdisk/al_aoula_laayoune/hls_snrt/index
```

Comment: thanks for your reply @Andrej Kesely , but I got this error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\firas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 23, in decode
    return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x90 in position 42182: character maps to <undefined>

Comment: thank you very very much Andrej Kesely  I fixed the error and here is my code :                       
import re

with open('f.txt', 'r', encoding='UTF8') as f_in, open('data_out.txt', 'w', encoding='UTF8') as f_out:
    txt = re.sub(r'(?<=^#EXTINF:)(-1.*,)', '', f_in.read(), flags=re.M)
    print(txt, file=f_out, end='')

Comment: but I didn't notice I still need the '-1'  and ',' to stay so how can I do that?

Comment: with this I could exclude the '-1' but I still need to exclude the ',' from deletion :    


with open('f.txt', 'r', encoding='UTF8') as f_in, open('data_out.txt', 'w', encoding='UTF8') as f_out:
    txt = re.sub(r'(?<=^#EXTINF:-1)( .*,)', '', f_in.read(), flags=re.M)
    print(txt, file=f_out, end='')

Comment: @FirasBayazed `txt = re.sub(r'(?<=^#EXTINF:-1)(.*,)', ',', f_in.read(), flags=re.M)` With this `-1` and `,` stays.

Answer (score 0):

here is the answer with excluding '-1' and ',' from deletion thanks to Andrej :

`import re
with open('f.txt', 'r', encoding='UTF8') as f_in, open('data_out.txt', 'w', encoding='UTF8') as f_out:
    txt = re.sub(r'(?<=^#EXTINF:-1)(.*,)', ',', f_in.read(), flags=re.M)
    print(txt, file=f_out, end='')`